# Having large arrays of memory addresses for Structures in OpenCl

Tags: c, arrays, opencl, heap-memory, c99

I'm new in OpenCl. I'm trying to simulate vector in OpenCl. In this regard, I have the following structure:

```
#define VECTOR_INIT_CAPACITY 126
typedef struct {
    int capacity;
    int total;
    __local void* items[VECTOR_INIT_CAPACITY];
} vector;

void vector_init( vector *v){
    v->capacity = VECTOR_INIT_CAPACITY;
    v->total = 0;
}

int vector_total(vector *v) {
    return v->total; 
}

void vector_add( vector *v, __local  void* item) {
   v->items[v->total] = item;
   v->total++;
}

__local void* vector_get(  vector *v, int index) {
    if (index >= 0 && index < v->total)
        return (v->items[index]);
    return NULL;
}
```

I also need to say that because of the project I am working on, I had to simulate the malloc function in OpenCl as follows which is working like a local heap for each GPU kernel:

```
typedef struct /*__attribute__((__packed__))*/{
    __local
    byte* ptr;
    int next;
}Heap;

__local void* malloc_(__local Heap *heap, int size) {

    uint old = heap->next;
    heap->next = heap->next + size;
    return heap->ptr + old;
 }
```

Regarding the structure alignment and OpenCl restrictions, Is it possible to have such a structure for vector. I am asking this question since my code crashes when I insert some items into a vector object.

For example, the following Kernel crashes:

```
__kernel void packet_routing(__global byte* heap_, __global uint* next,  __global byte* headers,__global int* packet_begining_index,
                         __global int* packet_length,__global uint* test_result){

    int gid = get_global_id(0);

    __local byte local_heap[50000];

    __local Heap heap ;
    heap.ptr = local_heap;
    heap.next = 0;//gid*MAX_HEAP_SIZE_FOR_EACH_KERNEL;

    vector layers;

    vector_init(&layers);
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 120; i ++){
        __local int *x = malloc_(&heap,sizeof(int));
        *x = i;
        vector_add(&layers,(__local void*)x);
    }

    __local int *z = (__local int*) vector_get(&layers,0);
    test_result[gid] = *z;
}
```

Comment: vector layers; is per thread because has no local keyword before it so each thread will have its own version?. x is not per thread, it is shared.

Answer (score 0):

How many items in your work group? If more than one, what is preventing race conditions on the shared (local) data? Without that you can't expect this to work.

Is this just test code? Because the memory usage doesn't seem conditional on anything, and in that case you'd be better off just making it fixed / static versus pseudo-dynamic (which is probably not very GPU friendly).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is only one item  in each  work group; so, there is not race condition. 
And yup. This is only a test code. My main code  is much more complicated using the defined malloc_ function quit often.